# flask app deployment on Heroku gives 500 erro

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have a flask application that is working fine locally, however when deployed on Heroku gives error - 500

provided below is the log fro Heroku - Any guidance will be help

```
020-07-19T15:26:53.980308+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `uwsgi uwsgi.ini`
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005660+00:00 app[web.1]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005777+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Sun Jul 19 15:26:56 2020] ***
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005777+00:00 app[web.1]: compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 19 July 2020 10:11:11
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005780+00:00 app[web.1]: os: Linux-4.4.0-1074-aws #78-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 15 03:53:20 UTC 2020
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005781+00:00 app[web.1]: nodename: 7626bfb4-732b-4bf1-aaee-9c0f34c4f14e
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005784+00:00 app[web.1]: machine: x86_64
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005803+00:00 app[web.1]: clock source: unix
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005804+00:00 app[web.1]: pcre jit disabled
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005804+00:00 app[web.1]: detected number of CPU cores: 8
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005806+00:00 app[web.1]: current working directory: /app
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005808+00:00 app[web.1]: detected binary path: /app/.heroku/python/bin/uwsgi
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005833+00:00 app[web.1]: your processes number limit is 256
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005833+00:00 app[web.1]: your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005851+00:00 app[web.1]: detected max file descriptor number: 10000
2020-07-19T15:26:56.005851+00:00 app[web.1]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2020-07-19T15:26:56.006016+00:00 app[web.1]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2020-07-19T15:26:56.006504+00:00 app[web.1]: uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :46173 fd 3
2020-07-19T15:26:56.006560+00:00 app[web.1]: Python version: 3.7.7 (default, May 19 2020, 10:55:09)  [GCC 7.5.0]
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022083+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022084+00:00 app[web.1]: Python main interpreter initialized at 0x559e3e177740
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022088+00:00 app[web.1]: your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022089+00:00 app[web.1]: your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022258+00:00 app[web.1]: mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
2020-07-19T15:26:56.022319+00:00 app[web.1]: *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2020-07-19T15:26:56.107306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-19T15:26:58.287355+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x559e3e177740 pid: 4 (default app)
2020-07-19T15:26:58.287370+00:00 app[web.1]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2020-07-19T15:26:58.287371+00:00 app[web.1]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 4)
2020-07-19T15:26:58.289069+00:00 app[web.1]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 8, cores: 1)
2020-07-19T15:27:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-19T15:28:31.907010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=equities-trade-capture.herokuapp.com request_id=e49b77fc-d2ca-4dc6-9c10-6b1ece7ffba6 fwd="103.143.147.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=183ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2020-07-19T15:28:31.907650+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 287412224 bytes/274MB} {rss usage: 54067200 bytes/51MB} [pid: 8|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.37.161.80 () {60 vars in 1151 bytes} [Sun Jul 19 15:28:31 2020] GET / => generated 290 bytes in 182 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 99 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
2020-07-19T15:28:35.710404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=equities-trade-capture.herokuapp.com request_id=d1beeb28-8d7d-4bd2-a29d-f7cd4be447b0 fwd="103.143.147.150" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and found out the following;

1. My app is configured to use Postgres as an add-on in Heroku
2. In the absence of Postgres add-on, it uses Sqllite3

When the add-on is configured, it gives a 500 error and if removed, it works.

When configuring Heroku with Postgres, are there any other code changes required other than the following;

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///data.db')
```